# Read user's emails Flutter / Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, flutter, email, architecture

I want to create an app where receiving an email with a certain String in the body triggers an event in my spring boot backend. I could not find any ressources on how to go about this properly.

My current idea is to store the user's email credentials in a local database on the phone of the user and just send the authentication token to my backend, so that my backend cannot read the user's credentials.

What do you think? Do you have any idea on how to approach this endeavour? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Google Mail, follow these guides from the Google API to achieve the above mentioned.

[1. Authorizing Your App with Gmail](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/web-server)

[2. Implementing Server-Side Authorization](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/web-server)